# Adicionar registo do PHP para a base de dados Mysql

Tags: php

Queria criar em PHP algo parecido com o que mostro na imagem para adicionar registos na base de dados:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém me pode ajudar, uma vez que sou novo em PHP?

Comment: presumo que tenhas conhecimento em base de dados por isso Tenta começar projetar a base de dados e a tabela adiciona os campos com tipo correspondente , será mais facil começar no php, quando conseguires tenta pesquisar por `conectar a base de dados PHP `

Comment: Já tenho isso pronto, tanto a base de dados como a parte da conexão, como também já tenho uma página pronta em php de consulta de dados à base de dados, agora tenho de fazer esta para inserir os registos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vou tentar te dar uma pequena ajuda

### **1º Primeiro**

Antes de tudo projeta a tua base de dados para que no php seja mais facil.

### **2º Segundo**

Já com a base de dados pensada cria o teu arquivo de conexão (**Connect.php**) deixo aqui um pequeno exemplo:

```
<?php
// qual é o servidor que estas a te conectar
$servidor = "localhost";

// nome de utilizador para acessar a base de dados
$user = "root";

// password do utilizador
$password = "password15634";

// qual é a base de dados a se conectar
$db = "base_de_dados";

// Cria a conexão e guarda-a numa variável para ser acessível mais tarde
$conn = new mysqli($servidor, $user, $password, $db);

// Verificar se a conexao foi bem sucedida!
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("A conexao com a base de dados falhou, mais detalhes: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

### **3º Terceiro**

Com o teu arquivo de conexão criado, junta-o a outro script(pagina) php (**index.php**) vamos tentar inserir na base de dados aqui esta o exemplo do 
**index.php**

```
//Incluimos o nosso arquivo de conexão para que possamos usar a variavel $conn
include('Connection.php');

// Vamos fazer a primeira requisição a base de dados
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO minha_tabela (produto, unid, qtd) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");

// ler mais aqui: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php
// vamos associar os ? com os valores pretendidos
$stmt->bind_param("ssi", $produto, $unid, $qtd);

// Vamos Atribuir valores para que possa ser introduzido na tabela exemplo
$produto = "Pneu de carro";
$unid = "09887234234";
$qtd = 4;

// finalmente executamos a nossa requisição a base de dados
$stmt->execute();
```

Se tudo der certo será introduzido um registo na tabela `minha_tabela` os estes valores:

```
$produto = "Pneu de carro";
$unid = "09887234234";
$qtd = 4;
```

Espero ter ajudado,

Para abrangeres mais teu conhecimento em php na parte de conexão a base de dados sugiro que entres nestes Links: *(links de exemplo deverá ter ai sites melhores)*

- [LINK1](https://www.kinghost.com.br/wiki/artigo/como-conectar-um-banco-de-dados-mysql-utilizando-php/).
- [LINK2](http://www.bosontreinamentos.com.br/php-programming/curso-de-php-inserindo-dados-em-um-banco-de-dados-mysql/).

Comment: Na parte do produto e no quarto queria utilizar uma combobox já com os produtos e quartos que existem na base de dados aparecerem e quando escolho o produto atribuir automaticamente a unidade, será que me podes ajudar a criar esse formulário?

Comment: tenta [dar aqui uma olhadela](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_radio)

Comment: 13dev, obrigado pela tua ajuda, já tenho o formulário quase pronto, só tenho um problema, que é ao selecionar o produto quero que me preencha automaticamente a unidade associada.